# null php string to json

Tags: php, json

this is my code

```
$token=file_get_contents("http://127.0.0.1/adsl/token.php?username=1350&password=3dddddddd");

$useragent = "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)";
$url="http://adsl.tci.ir/api/webservice/";
$arrSetHeaders = array(
    "User-Agent: $useragent",
    "Connection: keep-alive",
);
$post="data=&auth=$token&action=GetCustomerInfo&worker=android";

$ch  = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $arrSetHeaders);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);


$page= curl_exec($ch);
$page=json_decode($page,true);
```

`$page` is `null`

But when code directly in json_decode("MY CODE"); I do not have a problem

Comment: Your JSON string seems valid : https://3v4l.org/G3HWr

Comment: What's the value of `$page` after `curl_exec()`? Could you post the result of a `var_dump($page)`?

Comment: @Syscall  String

Comment: It prints only `String`? If not, please add it in your question.

Comment: @Syscall yes only print string

Comment: A `var_dump()` never prints only "string".